# Magento - Edit Container2 in Catalog

Tags: magento, block, wrapper, magento-1.8

I need help in editing the catalog view on Magento 1.8.

I have a configurable product with two attributes (orange box) as you can see below.
(Both of them need to stay attributes)

Additionaly there are some necessary custom product options (blue box).

This both attributes down in the orange box are important to set the price and should be chosen at first but I can't get them over the (not *that* important) custom options.

I did read through a bunch of threads here and noted that container2 gets build in

> app/design/frontend/default/TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml

but I don't get where to edit to change the sequence of the building process of container2.

I hope some of you already managed to edit the containers.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvH0L.png

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the layout/catalog.xml in your TEMPLATE location and modify this part:

```
 <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
     <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
     <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
     <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
     <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
 </block>
```

As you can see I swapped the wrapper and wrapper.bottom actions. Then you can adjust the CSS styling as it won't look pretty by default. Best of luck!